# Change width of child element without knowing the child element ID

Tags: javascript

I've cloned a parent div and set it to width 285px. It has a child div that I want to set width at 270px. I don't want to touch the original child, just the child of the clone. This is my code so far and first half works but the second half involving the child of the cloned parent doesn't. Can someone help me please?

```
var div = document.getElementById('parent'),
    clone = div.cloneNode(true);
clone.id = "clonedparent";
clone.style.position='absolute';
clone.style.width="285px";
clone.style.overflowX="hidden";
document.body.appendChild(clone);

var child = document.getElementById('clonedparent').firstChild
child.id = "childofclonedparent";
child.style.width="270px";
```

The main objective is to make the text within the clone and child wrap within a width of 270px. The HTML is a youtube watch page. This is part of a greasemonkey script to place a dupped description box next to the video so I can read transcripts and lyrics while watching the video.

Comment: Provide your html structure and a fiddle please.

Comment: try to replace the assignment of child to: var child = clone.firstChild;

Comment: Your second half code is not formatted right. Is this just a question typo or does your real code look like the same? Now you have `document.getElementById('clonedparent').firstChild`. Check this resource for detailed info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.firstChild

Comment: Ooops! Fixed it with firstElementChild instead of firstChild. `var child = clone.firstElementChild;`

Answer (score 0):

Solved by OP ([Secretss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3809242/secretss)) on comments.

---

> Ooops! Fixed it with `firstElementChild` instead of `firstChild`.

```
var child = clone.firstElementChild;
```